# VLC 2.2.1 using Qt dialog

Tags: upgrade, gtk, 15.10, qt

When I upgraded from 15.04 to 15.10, this included a new version of VLC, as well as a newer Qt. VLC now uses the Qt file open dialog, but I want the GTK one back. I have already checked VLC themes and qt4-qtconfig, which make no difference to the dialog when changing the theme. Is there a qt5-config or an advanced VLC setting I've missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just hit the same issue after upgrading to VLC 2.2.1-5+b1 on Debian Testing, and solved it by installing the libqt5libqgtk2 package.

Recently Used is back in the file chooser and I'm once again a happy camper.

Comment: You=Awesome. Thank you! This question had so little activity until now that I got an achievement, so thanks for finding it as well.

Comment: After hours of trying to get the native open-file-dialog on xubuntu 15.10, finally found this answer: thank you!